# Is there a human-readable serialization format that handles non-String keys?

Tags: serialization

I'm serializing objects (Scala).  My program allows Map[X,Y] where X and Y are any number of types, including objects and collections.

I can serialize to JSON or YAML but these formats require keys for objects (aka Maps) must be a String, while my original object environment easily permits non-String keys.

I can (and have) serialized my non-String keys into Strings (which works but can produce very ugly output).  I've even serialized to a JSON-ish (but noncanonical) format where the rendered "near-JSON" shows non-String object keys, but that's nonstandard and wouldn't be terribly useful outside of my own code.

Are there other options?  Is there a human-readable format that can handle non-String object/Map keys?

Comment: A few years late, but... YAML actually may use non-string keys, they start with a question mark. Check [the spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), search for "indicate a complex mapping key". I hope this helps someone in the future.